Is it true that $\forall a,b \in G, \exists n=n(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}$, depending on $a$ and $b$, with $ab=b^na^n$ implies $G$ is an abelian group?
Let $G$ be a finite group. If $\forall a,b \in G, \exists n \in \mathbb{Z}, ab=b^n a^n$, is it true that $G$ is necessarily an abelian group ?
I have searched a non abelian counterexample with a computer.
If $|G|$ is a prime number, $G$ is abelian.
If $|G|=4$, $G\simeq \mathbb{Z}/4 \mathbb{Z}$ or $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2$. So $G$ is abelian.
If $|G|=2p$ where $p$ is a prime number $\geq 3$, let $H$ be the Sylow-$p$-subgroup of $G$. Then $|G|/|H|=2$ so $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. And $H \simeq \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. So
(1) $G \simeq \mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}$ , or
(2) $G \simeq \mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z} \rtimes \{-1,1 \}$.
In the case (1), $G$ is abelian.
In the case (2), let $a=(1,-1) \in G$ and $b=(-1,-1) \in G$. Then $a^2=(0,1)=e$ and $b^2=(0,1)=e$. So $b^n a^n=e$ if $n \equiv 0 \pmod 2$ or $b^n a^n =ba=(-2,1)$ if $n \equiv 1\pmod 2$. But $ab=(2,1)$ and $(2,1)\neq (-2,1)$ in $G$ because $p$ is a prime number $\geq 3$, and $(2,1) \neq e=(0,1)$. So we don't have $ab=b^na^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.
If $|G|=p^2$ ($p$ a prime number), then $G$ is an abelian group.
So I have searched with computer counterexample where $|G|=pq$ with $q>p>2$, or $|G|=pqr$ ($p,q,r$ prime numbers), but I have found none.
Thanks !

Does the $n$ depend on $a$ and $b$? Or do you mean, whether there is a nonabelian group having the identity $ab=b^na^n$ for some $n>1$?

@Dietrich Burde : The $n$ depends on $a$ and $b$.

For more context, see  your previous question. I think you should post this one again at MO, and not here.

It is worth noting that the case in which $n(a,b) = n$ is fixed is trivially true. Indeed, plugging in $b = 1$ yields $a = a^n$ and similarly also $b = b^n$; whence $ab = b^na^n = ba$ and the group is abelian. In fact, one doesn't even need all group axioms in this case, nor the finiteness of $G$

@MikeDaas : thanks for your answer.

@DietrichBurde : yes, the question is similar, because $ab=b^na^n \iff b^{-1}aba^{-1}=b^{n-1}a^{n-1}$. If $u=b^{-1}$, $v=a$ and $k=-(n-1)$, it is $uvu^{-1}v^{-1}=u^{k}v^{-k}$.

There is some experimental evidence for your conjecture.
Below you find some GAP code that checks your conjecture for all groups of a given order, or whose order belongs to a given range. It confirms that your conjecture is true for all groups of order $\leq 1000$.
# Checks for two elements a,b of a group G if b * a = a^i * b^i for some i.
CheckPropertyForPair := function(G, a, b)
    local max, p, q, i;

    max := Size(G) - 1;
    p := b * a;
    q := One(G);

    for i in [0..max] do
        if p = q then
            return true; 
        fi;
        q := a * q * b;
        if q = One(G) then
            return false;
        fi;
    od;

    return false; 
end;

# Checks if a group G has property P: if all elements a,b of G have the property above.
CheckPropertyForGroup := function(G)
    local elements;
    elements := Elements(G);
    return ForAll(elements, a -> ForAll(elements, b -> CheckPropertyForPair(G, a, b)));
end;

# Checks for a group if the conjecture "P => Abelian" is true.
CheckConjectureForGroup := function(G)
    return (not CheckPropertyForGroup(G)) or IsAbelian(G);
end;


# Checks if the conjecture is true for all groups of order n.
CheckConjectureForGroupsOfOrder := function(n)
    return ForAll(AllSmallGroups(n), G -> CheckConjectureForGroup(G));
end;

# Checks if the conjecture is true for all groups of orders >= min and <= max.
CheckConjectureForGroupsUpToOrder := function(min, max)
    local i, checked, skipped;
    skipped := [512, 768]; # orders that take too long to check
    for i in [min..max] do
        if i in skipped then
            Print("Skip order ", i,"\n");
            continue;
        fi;
        Print("Checking conjecture for groups of order ", i, " ... ");
        checked := CheckConjectureForGroupsOfOrder(i);
        if checked then
            Print("✅", "\n");
        else
            Print("❌", "\n");
            break;
        fi;
    od;
end;

For example, you can run CheckConjectureForGroupsUpToOrder(1, 1000).
Notice that there are many groups of order $2^k$, and this slows down the computation a lot. To speed things up for a quick analysis, you might want to skip these and other orders by adding them to the skipped list.
For these orders, we may use the following function instead, which also shows the current progress.
# Checks if the conjecture is true for all groups of order n
# and prints the progress. Useful when there are many groups to check.
CheckProgressConjectureForGroupsOfOrder := function(n)
    local G, i, numberGroups, verified, percentage, percentageNew;
    numberGroups := NumberSmallGroups(n);
    percentage := 0;
    Print("There are ", numberGroups, " small groups of order ",n,"\n");
    Print("Checking the conjecture ...\n");
    Print("0%\n");
    for i in [1..numberGroups] do
        G := SmallGroup(n, i);
        percentageNew := Int(100 * (i-1)/numberGroups);
        if percentageNew > percentage then
            percentage := percentageNew;
            Print(percentage,"%\n");
        fi;
        verified := CheckConjectureForGroup(G);
        if not verified then
            Print("The conjecture is wrong for the small group of index ", i,"\n");
            break;
        fi;
    od;
    Print("Done\n");
end;

I ran this for $n=768$ and it confirmed the conjecture in about 50 minutes. I also ran this for $n=512$ and it confirmed the conjecture in about 12 hours.

Thanks for your answer. "Prime powers sometimes take too long" : is it because there are too many groups of order a prime power ?

Yes exactly. I will make a second run today including prime powers.

I have improved the code and also did run it for more orders.

@marco2013 Personally I think you should not accept my answer. It does not prove (or even attempt to prove) your conjecture. It just gives some examples where it is true. In a quite literal sense, I have proved your conjecture for 0% of all groups. I posted it just so that others can also use the code to verify the conjecture for some (many) groups.

Thank you. There is a lot of groups of order a prime powers. What is the reason ? With the computer, I have seen there is a lot of groups of order $60$ too (I'm not sure).
